# ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save() hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-7

I am trying to save data in table using hibernate. My entity looks like

```
@Entity
public class Nemocnica  implements java.io.Serializable {

         @Id 
         @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         //@Column(name="N_ID")
         private BigDecimal NId;
         private String adresa;
         private Set sanitkas = new HashSet(0);

        public Nemocnica() {
        }


        public Nemocnica( String adresa) {
            this.NId = NId;
        }

        public Nemocnica(BigDecimal NId, String adresa) {
            this.NId = NId;
            this.adresa = adresa;
        }
        public Nemocnica(BigDecimal NId, String adresa, Set sanitkas) {
           this.NId = NId;
           this.adresa = adresa;
           this.sanitkas = sanitkas;
        }

        public BigDecimal getNId() {
            return this.NId;
        }

        public void setNId(BigDecimal NId) {
            this.NId = NId;
        }
        public String getAdresa() {
            return this.adresa;
        }

        public void setAdresa(String adresa) {
            this.adresa = adresa;
        }
        public Set getSanitkas() {
            return this.sanitkas;
        }

        public void setSanitkas(Set sanitkas) {
            this.sanitkas = sanitkas;
        }
    }
```

And the way i want to insert data into it

```
public static Integer addNemocnica( String adresa ){
      Integer ID = null;
      try{
         Nemocnica n  = new Nemocnica( adresa);
         ID = (Integer) session.save(n); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
      return ID;
   }
```

Yet it still throws error

> ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

I tried everything i found including

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

I am using oracle database and the table i am trying to insert data into has set autoincrement to true. How can fix this?

Thanks for help

Comment: GenerationType.IDENTITY is not correct. you need to provide GenerationType,sequence

Comment: GenerationType.IDENTITY is not correct. you need to provide GenerationType,sequence if you already have sequence setup in your database.

Comment: GenerationType.SEQUENCE does not help , error remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 4:**

It's not clear how is your tables setup in DB. I am assuming tables are setup like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Nemocnica` (
`NId` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`adresa` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
....
PRIMARY KEY (`NId`)
```

)

If that's how your table is created, then

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="N_ID")
private BigDecimal NId;
```

should work. Try matching the names of the columns in the table to the fields in the Java class. If not, then show us your sql table how it was created. If you don't know how to get the table creation schema, you will need to look it up online for your specific Database. You may also want to lookup how to get the sequence schema out of the Database (if schema exists, you will find it).

### **End of Edit 4.**

If you are using a sequence in Oracle database, then `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is not correct. you need to provide GenerationType.SEQUENCE in strategy attribute. Code would will look like this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
generator = "SomeEntityGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SomeEntityGenerator",
sequenceName = "SomeEntitySequence")
private BigDecimal NId;
```

But the above code will create a new sequence. If you already have a sequence ready and setup in Oracle DB then you would need to provide:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
```

If you go this route, you have to specify the `allocationSize` which needs to be the same value that the DB sequence uses as its "auto increment".

Try this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
```

`sequenceName` attribute is the name of the sequence in DB. So you will put that name in that attribute.

The last resort is to manually retrieve the value of the sequence from DB. Then set it yourself. Retrieving part would look like this

```
Long getNext() {
Query query = 
    session.createSQLQuery("select MYSEQ.nextval as num from dual")
        .addScalar("num", StandardBasicTypes.BIG_INTEGER);

return ((BigInteger) query.uniqueResult()).longValue();
}
```

But for this to work you would have to modify your code, which I suggest you don't.

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate about @SequenceGenerator annotation? In my database i have set increment by one , i have used sqldeveloper

Comment: @trolkura I updated my answer. Can you test this first?

Comment: @trolkura can you try this: @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")

Comment: @trolkura can you tell me if you already have a sequence in DB or not?

Comment: if you autoncrement , yes , its set to increment id by 1

Comment: No that's not what I asked. Did you setup a sequence in DB or not?

Comment: @Feraz Durrani i checked the databse and its propably not set, ( the database is over year old i do not remmember setting it up )

Comment: Oh thats the issue. Man I don't know what to do now :(

Comment: Not that i read about it , sequence is the only way how to create autoincrement , so i propably did set it up

Answer (score 0):

Does you set the autoincrement flag in your database for the primary key n_id?

If you use `tx.commit()` you need to start the transaction with `tx.begin()`

Comment: Yep , the autoincrement is set in database. tx.begin is set  in class

Comment: Does the entity properties correctly mapped with the db columns. Use the @Column Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Does the entity properties correctly mapped with the db columns. Use the @Column Annotations. In your example it's commented out. Do you have active the auto validation at startup you can set it in the persistence.xml?

Comment: I tried it with @Column anotation didn work either. What do u mean by validation startup?, Now when i look at my project ,persistence.xml is not even generated

Comment: You can set the property  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Comment: if you have no persistence.XML you can set it over the sourcecode

Comment: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto if hibernate starts the initialization of the session it can validate your entities with the database. This property needs a value for the full doc of the this you can look into the hibernate documentation.

Comment: What property should i assign to it? I set it as validate which didnt help

Comment: Yes use validate in the console log there must be now a row with table ... found

Comment: yes , it is now , however im confused , where does this lead to?

Comment: If something wrong with your entity the validation says you what's wrong. But it looks good.